# Postfix reject mail with result of spamassasin content_filter

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I have a running Mailserver using Postfix and Dovecot. I also configured spamassasin like in this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin). Spam is properly marked as such and apropriate headers are added.

Now I want to reject the spam-mails based on the result of spamassasin. How could i achieve this. I would prefer a solution without using amavis cause of its very complex configuration.

I tried it using header_checks but this does not work, maybe because the spamassasin content_filter is executed after the header_check.

Comment: Have you checked [How to make spamassasin reject mail based on score](http://serverfault.com/questions/146855/how-to-make-spamassasin-reject-mail-based-on-score)?

Comment: Yes but the only solution there is the usage of amavis. I would prefer a solution without it.