# Blocking empty subject line emails from being sent or received?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, spamassassin

How can I configure Postfix, Dovecot, and/or SpamAssasin to reject all incoming and outgoing emails with empty subject line emails?

I am running on a Debian 8.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to REJECT the mail, which would be a good idea as it also informs the sender that you don't want to receive mail with empty subject, you should use Postfix [header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html).

Add `header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks` to your `main.conf` and then add there this regular expression for empty Subject:

```
/^subject: *$/   REJECT  Please add subject to your mail.
```

In order to use this *Perl Compatible Regular Expression* you must have [Postfix PCRE map support](http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html) (from package `postfix-pcre`) installed.

Only limitation with `header_checks` is that it cannot recognize if the `Subject` field is totally missing. This problem you could address by scoring it higher on  SpamAssassin. For global configuration `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf` and for user configuration `~/.spamassassin/user_prefs` add:

```
score MISSING_SUBJECT          30
```

If you need to REJECT mails without `Subject` header, not just flag and/or quietly remove the mail, you can [make SpamAssasin reject mail based on score](https://serverfault.com/a/569372/274176) by using it as a proxy-filter for Postfix.

Comment: Did not work for me.  I edited `/etc/posftfix/main.cf` and then restarted the service - and now I get `header_checks map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later` and `warning: maildrop/08E14833B6: error writing B4C1481F54: queue file write error` and `warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pcre` and `warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks lookup error for "Received: by FQDN (Postfix, from userid 33)`

Comment: I have installed that, and the install was OK. When I run ` postconf -m` I get mysql but not pcre.

Comment: Thank you. I had to install `postfix-pcre` on top the `postfix-mysql`. It works now (PS, I added that note to your answer)

Comment: I rejected your edit because it seemed like it would be better as answer on its own.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Please erase that comment. You do not need `postfix-mysql`. You need `postfix-pcre` under Deb/Ubuntu/etc. MySQL/postfix-mysql & any assoc libs has nothing to do with the question at all (or answer). Consult. = http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html / https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/postfix-pcre

Comment: @bshea: Thanks. Done.