# Configure Amavis with custom spamassassin rules

Tags: email, spamassassin, amavis

How can I configure Amavis to apply specific rules from SpamAssassin, like

```
score MISSING_SUBJECT          30
```

from [Blocking empty subject line emails from being sent or received?](https://serverfault.com/questions/842344/blocking-empty-subject-line-emails-from-being-sent-or-received)

I run Amavisd-new 2.11.0, including the libraries from Spamassassin 3.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amavis should read the standard configuration of spamassassin, so you can put your custom configuration in "/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf" (or similar) and it should just work.

Comment: And Amavis needs to be reloaded/restarted to read the new spamassassin rules.

Comment: Note: Not all Spamassassin directives are observed if using amavis-new (though it does read the sa cf files in). Rule score overrides should be observed, though. For instance using `score RCVD_IN_ZEN 4.5` in local.cf will work. Other directives not working should have an amavis-new counterpart. Please consult https://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/#faq-spam for info on amavis-new `$sa_` directives.